# Rodar o firebase em um único domínio

Tags: segurança, firebase

Eu estou aprendendo a trabalhar com firebase recentemente.
Fiz um simples exemplo retirando a autenticação do usuário para conversar no chat.

Dessa forma preciso implementar algum tipo de segurança, então eu tenho duas dúvidas com relação a segurança do firebase:

Como posso configurar para que o firebase rode em somente um domínio?
Como posso esconder a minha chave de acesso do meu firebase que fica no código javascript?

Comment: Você não precisa esconder a chave, o leitura/escrita do seu site/app é definido nas regras dentro do console do projeto firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Sobre o domínio, você pode configurar esse tipo de acesso no console do firebase. Lá, acrescente os dominios que poderão acessar. Por padrão ele vem marcado com o `localhost`

Sobre esconder, creio que não seja possível, mas a partir do momento que você fizer um bom controle de domínio, essa questão não se torna mais necessário, mas se ainda quiser esconder, procure por ferramentas de ofuscação